# Substitute cipher characters for words (solved, maybe useful for others)

Tags: python, arrays, string, row, substitution

*I started writing some of my questions down in here but I found a few of the answers and figured out the rest. Leaving it here for future reference in case it helps anyone else.*

I got very inspired by the 'number stations' broadcasting messages assumed to be encrypted with one time pads. So, preparing for a D&D game I wanted to encode a message into a list of words, where the word used alternates every second time a character is used.

With the one time pad I started encrypting the message manually, made it 7 characters in. Then realized I had already made at least one mistake. Then started writing python program to actually encode it right.

I'm aware I might not have found elegant solutions, however it does work without using numpy.

```
matrix = [["A", "treatment", "snails", 1],  # massive 2d array. 
          ["B", "two", "texture", 1],  # Saner people would just do lower caps.
          ["C", "induce", "knotty", 1],
          ["D", "lowly", "unused", 1],
          ["E", "income", "grip", 1],
          ["F", "talented", "squeak", 1],
          ["G", "intelligent", "dependent", 1],
          ["H", "nest", "border", 1],
          ["I", "excuse", "delay", 1],
          ["J", "sudden", "gigantic", 1],
          ["K", "stew", "tooth", 1],
          ["L", "quack", "hole", 1],
          ["M", "eggs", "married", 1],
          ["N", "vessel", "punch", 1],
          ["O", "embarrass", "scatter", 1],
          ["P", "lace", "draconian", 1],
          ["Q", "lopsided", "attraction", 1],
          ["R", "blade", "average", 1],
          ["S", "workable", "way", 1],
          ["T", "harmony", "waste", 1],
          ["U", "thick", "warlike", 1],
          ["V", "island", "drop", 1],
          ["W", "rail", "null", 1],
          ["X", "misty", "earth", 1],
          ["Y", "camp", "clip", 1],
          ["Z", "fax", "stop", 1],
          ["a", "crooked", "left", 1],
          ["b", "thick", "cook", 1],
          ["c", "sense", "top", 1],
          ["d", "auspicious", "title", 1],
          ["e", "few", "error", 1],
          ["f", "longing", "fearless", 1],
          ["g", "scarce", "bone", 1],
          ["h", "eyes", "hushed", 1],
          ["i", "doctor", "save", 1],
          ["j", "puncture", "dashing", 1],
          ["k", "snotty", "foregoing", 1],
          ["l", "callous", "dolls", 1],
          ["m", "town", "wind", 1],
          ["n", "thirsty", "fear", 1],
          ["o", "thoughtful", "actually", 1],
          ["p", "ticket", "rings", 1],
          ["q", "view", "ancient", 1],
          ["r", "different", "hot", 1],
          ["s", "abrasive", "bag", 1],
          ["t", "excellent", "care", 1],
          ["u", "testy", "curious", 1],
          ["v", "complex", "reflective", 1],
          ["w", "smash", "kick", 1],
          ["x", "office", "helpful", 1],
          ["y", "noiseless", "gainful", 1],
          ["z", "minister", "false", 1],
          [" ", "linen", "power", 1],
          ["0", "subtract", "pathetic", 1],
          ["1", "employ", "bumpy", 1],
          ["2", "substance", "tow", 1],
          ["3", "towering", "probable", 1],
          ["4", "lake", "eye", 1],
          ["5", "moon", "yielding", 1],
          ["6", "crazy", "representative", 1],
          ["7", "actor", "rice", 1],
          ["8", "unwieldy", "manage", 1],
          ["9", "wing", "cowardly", 1],
          [".", "driving", "simplistic", 1],
          [",", "comb", "one", 1],
          ["?", "provide", "part", 1]]

text = "What a lovely night to post on Stack overflow. I'd be interested in having this as a program that asks for input text. Maybe as an .exe file, so I wont have to run it from pycharm." #the input text.

result = ""
n = 0  #thought I'd also like to know how long the string was/how many words it generated.

for char in text:  # repeat all the stuff for each character in the original text.
    row = 0
    n += 1

    for row in range(66):  # for every character, go down through array until matching char found.
        if matrix[row][0] == char: 
            if matrix[row][3] % 2 == 0:
                alternate = 2
            else:
                alternate = 1
            matrix[row][3] += 1# the number at the end of each row is a counter for 
            # how many times the character has already been used.
            result += matrix[row][alternate] + " - "  # concatenate everything.
            # print(matrix[row][alternate])  # neatly list everything on single lines. Not needed. Currently off.
length = len(result)
result = result[:length - 3]
result += "." #removes the, now no longer needed ' - ' from the end of the string and add a'.'. Also not needed.
print(n) #List the length of the text/the number of words.
print(result)
```

I wonder how quickly I'd get a visit from law enforcement if I got a ham radio and started using this to broadcast messages.

Side note. In the D&D game, someone has gotten lazy and is reusing the same one time pad. A new one for every encrypted clue players found would be impossible to decipher and take ages. However I wanted the program, as a programming exercise, but also for consistency. I case they do want to decipher it.

The output would be rather ominous to have read out loud over the radio, with seemingly random intervals.

Output with my example string, if anyone is curious;

```
181
rail - eyes - crooked - excellent - linen - left - power - callous - thoughtful - complex - few - dolls - noiseless - linen - thirsty - doctor - scarce - hushed - care - power - excellent - actually - linen - ticket - thoughtful - abrasive - care - power - actually - fear - linen - workable - excellent - crooked - sense - snotty - power - thoughtful - reflective - error - different - longing - callous - actually - smash - driving - linen - excuse - auspicious - power - thick - few - linen - save - thirsty - care - error - hot - few - bag - excellent - error - title - power - doctor - fear - linen - eyes - left - complex - save - thirsty - bone - power - care - hushed - doctor - abrasive - linen - crooked - bag - power - left - linen - rings - different - thoughtful - scarce - hot - crooked - town - power - excellent - eyes - left - care - linen - crooked - abrasive - foregoing - bag - power - fearless - actually - different - linen - save - fear - ticket - testy - excellent - power - care - few - office - excellent - simplistic - linen - eggs - left - gainful - cook - error - power - crooked - abrasive - linen - left - thirsty - power - driving - few - helpful - error - linen - longing - doctor - dolls - few - comb - power - bag - thoughtful - linen - delay - power - kick - actually - fear - care - linen - hushed - crooked - reflective - error - power - excellent - thoughtful - linen - hot - curious - thirsty - power - save - care - linen - fearless - different - actually - wind - power - rings - noiseless - top - eyes - left - hot - town - simplistic - linen.
```

Comment: Maybe the [CodeReview] website would be a better place to post this and get ffedback. Because I don't think just posting for yourself fits the rules here.

Comment: Thank you, was not aware of Code Review. Still leaving this here though, my biggest problem was searching through array and have it return the corresponding row. Not an answer I found anywhere else.

Comment: You seem to not know Python very well : you can iterate on your list directly, or use `enumerate` for example. I think that a code review would teach you lots of things :)

Comment: ```enumerate```does  seem useful. I've made some stuff in python in the past, but not my main language. Just shaking off some of the rust.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).